# Restoring google translation to its default settings

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to read some translated web pages. When I right-clicked the page, the option for [translate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMorS.jpg) is in a different language than it is for my [browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvZKN.jpg). I've tried changing the browser language settings back to English, but the option for Amharic still shows up as the default. How can both settings match each other?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm which internet browser you are using?

In Google Chrome the language settings are in settings>advanced>languages, if this is the browser you are using can you confirm that English is at the top of the list and selected as default for both 'languages' and 'spelling' you can also try removing Amharic from the list of languages all together. After changes are made to the language, Chrome requires a relaunch. There are no specific settings for translation language.